# laravel project routes not working on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, azure

I am facing problem while uploading my laravel project to shared server, microsoft azure. I can't access routes other than / . My route file has following code :

```
Route::get(/, function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

It's basically I used php artisan make:auth to generate login signup default functionality.

I can access my /route by visiting :

http://40.121.138.22/monrostudio/public/

But can't visit other routes like /login, /register or any other I created.

Comment: You should have a virtual host that points to the **public** directory and also a **.htaccess** in the *public* directory, which will take care of the routing.

Comment: Which Azure Service you deployed your application to? Web Apps or others?

Answer (score 0):

The page that loads for `http://40.121.138.22/monrostudio/public/` according to your link should load when you go to the root route like `http://40.121.138.22/` or `http://40.121.138.22/home`.

This is how I would troubleshoot it:

1) go to the control panel of your hosting provider and make sure you installed and configured your Laravel project in the `public` folder or `public_html`, whatever your hosting provider instructions say

2) make sure your set up your domain's DNS according to your host's instructions (I'm 99% sure its not an issue but its worth checking.  Hosting Laravel on shared servers is not very straightforward, as I recently found out myself.

3) Check your routes file. Make sure you have you have routes to all the pages you want to go pointing to the existing controllers. Controller for `auth` is `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php`. The `AuthController` is the one that sends users down the `login` and `register` path. It is also the one that redirects registered users away from `register` page and logged in users away from `login` page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you haven't setup Mod_Rewrite on your server.

Follow below steps for enabling mod_rewrite for **Apache Server**.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

(Open apache config file, And find below lines)

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

and change it to

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And finally

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And then you will see it working.
Hope it helps.